# Compiler says that I'm not specified type for Set (type mismatch)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am a new learner of scala learning about sets. i want to add my parameters to the set and then return it from a function.

```
def singleElementSet(elem: Int): Set ={
    var newSet = Set()
    newSet+= elem
  }
```

I tried this but it gives me errors like:

```
type Set takes type parameters
- type Set takes type parameters
```

and

for elem

```
type mismatch;  found   : elem.type (with underlying type Int)  required: Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like

```
def singleElementSet(elem: Int): Set[Int] = {
    val newSet = Set.empty[Int]
    newSet + elem
}
```

or you could just create the set directly

```
def singleElementSet(elem: Int) = Set(elem)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define what Set will have in it by Set[Int] in your example.  When creating a new Set, you either have to specify it's type like this:

```
val newSet = Set.empty[Int]
```

or initialize the Set with something:

```
val newSet = Set(1)
```

However, you will likely either have to use var OR a mutable Set to accomplish much.  For example, your code should look something like this:

```
var newSet = Set.empty[Int]
def singleElementSet(elem: Int): Set[Int] = {
    newSet+= elem
}
```

(You can't define the Set as an empty Set everytime you call the method or the results will not add up)

Comment: Thanks Jordan for reply, i added Set[Int] but it still gives me 
"type Set takes type parameters" error.

Comment: That is because you are leaving the parameters for Set() empty.

Comment: var newSet = Set.empty[Int]
    newSet+= elem
still getting the error.

Comment: You are still getting the same error?  It is working fine in my REPL.

Comment: @JordanDenison: I think you wanted newSet + elem, rather than newSet += elem, maybe ?

Comment: The Set that you and I have defined is immutable, so simply calling + on it doesn't do anything (and += wouldn't work because it's a val).  I changed the variable type to var (mutable) and by calling += I am re-setting the value to the original Set plus the Int being added (which is a single Set with the value of the Int in it).

Comment: I'm afraid you're not right, yes the Set is immutable, but you can do newSet + elem on it, returning a new immutable Set that holds only elem.

Comment: Well += is working in my REPL and + is not, I'll have to look into that further

Comment: Oh I see now, you are just returning the new Set, not reassigning to a val.  Your way is the more functional and correct I suppose : )